# How to prevent a form from reloading onSubmit while writing unit test in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test which is testing that a user should not be able to submit a form until the form has been filled out. Now, everything works as it should and my test passes, but my issue is since the default behaviour of submitting a form is reloading the page, which is making my unit test stuck in an infinite reloading cycle every time it is executed.

One potential solution for this was changing the submit button type from submit -> button, but that will break the functionality, so I want to defer from doing that.

I have also tried commenting out the alert part in the typescipt file but that didn't made a difference either.

```js
it('should keep the save btn disabled until recording has been done', () => {
  spyOn(component, "onSave");
  fixture.detectChanges();
  let button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#createRecording')).nativeElement;
  console.log(button);
  button.click();
  expect(component.onSave).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
})
```

```html
<div class="web-recording-setup-container">
  <form [formGroup]="webRecordingForm" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
    <div>
      <div class="row" style="padding: 5px 10px;">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vrecord" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500;">Name your Recording:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="vrecord" formControlName="FileName" placeholder="Enter recording name ..." [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.FileName.touched && f.FileName.errors }">
            <div *ngIf="f.FileName.touched && f.FileName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f.FileName.errors.required">File Name is required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="padding: 5px 10px; text-align: center;">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding: 5px; ">
          <!-- ADD STOP WATCH - START -->
          <div class="circle">
            <span class="timer" id="display">{{audioTimer}}</span>
          </div>
          <!-- ADD STOP WATCH - END -->

          <br />
          <button class="btn" type="button" (click)="initiateRecording(); start()" title="Start Recording" style="background-color: #bd4932; color: white;" [disabled]="recording">
                        <i *ngIf="recording" class="fa fa-circle fa-lg recordingHide" style="color:white;"
                            id="recCtrl1"></i>
                        <i *ngIf="!recording" class="fa fa-microphone fa-lg recordingShow" id="recCtrl2"></i>
                    </button>
          <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" (click)="stopRecording(); pause()" title="Stop Recording">
                        <i class="fa fa-stop fa-lg"></i>
                    </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="padding: 5px 10px;">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <!-- cant attach click event to controls attribute -->
          <audio controls *ngIf="url" style="width: 100%;">
                        <source [src]="sanitize(url)" type="audio/wav">
                        Your browser does not support the audio format.
                    </audio>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="padding: 20px 10px;">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

          <button type="submit" [disabled]="!webRecordingForm.valid" class="btn btn-lg" style="float: right; margin-left: 5px;color: white;background-color:#105b63 ;" id="createRecording"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i> Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

component.ts

```js
onSave() {
    //console.log("on Save Recordings");
    if (this.record !== undefined || this.record != null) {
      this.OutputSaveRecording.emit("Clicked");
    }
    else {
      alert("No Recording Found");
    }

  }
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the unit test code you supplied that would be submitting the form. Maybe giving us the code that is called from the unit test will help (e.g. button click calls => `initiateRecording(); start();`).

Comment: i am talking about btn with id createRecording that one submits the form

Comment: apologies, I must have misread what button was being clicked in the unit test;

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `event.PreventDefault();` on onSubmit

Comment: Can you pls elaborate a little on how to execute your solution.

i tried doing `<form [formGroup]="webRecordingForm" (ngSubmit)="onSave($event)">` and then  changing my TS to 

`onSave(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log("on Save Recordings");
    if (this.record !== undefined || this.record != null) {
      this.OutputSaveRecording.emit("Clicked");
    }
    else {
      alert("No Recording Found");
    }`

but it didnt work and the page is still reloading.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103066/how-to-use-event-preventdefault-in-angularjs/46103107

Comment: thank you for the response but I am still looking for angular 12 way to do that so, far I have only been able to find jquery, angularJS way.

Answer (score 0):

I would be smarter about how you are writing the unit test.

e.g.

Instead of calling `button.click()`, I would just execute the code that is linked in the template. IMO, there is no real reason the test that the binding in angular is working.

```
it('should keep the save btn disabled until recording has been done', () => {
  spyOn(component, "onSave");
  fixture.detectChanges();
  component.initiateRecording();
  component.start();
  expect(component.onSave).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
})
```

Also, you may consider rewriting your expect block to acutally check that the submit button is disabled OR change the it statement to reflect what you are actually testing. e.g. something like ... "onSave should not be called if the recording is not complete etc."

Are you importing the Forms Module into your TestBed?
re: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12757

If not, that may be your issue.

Comment: thank you for your ans but I all I want from my question is to figure out how to stop the reloading. I can work on optimizing the test case later. your written test will pass without any error since onSave() function is called only when save btn is clicked and since you removed the `button.click()` it is never going to get executed.

Comment: does the problem only present in the unit test runner?

Comment: yes works fine when I follow the steps manually.

Comment: I found a related github issue that may be relevant, and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: hey thank you so much! adding the FormModule and ReactiveFormModule inside imports did the trick for me